# What are these interior decorators home items?

Tags: home

I am renovating an old hotel and found these curtain or blind plastic and rope pulley items in a box.I haven't a clue what they used for?[image]

Comment: This would be a better fit on [DIY](https://diy.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Product identification is not within the intended scope of this site. See [About Lifehacks](http://bit.ly/1F9XABO). Sorry about the confusion.